# removeObjects from RLMResults

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, realm-cocoa

How can I remove objects from RLMResults. I mean in NSMutableArray there is a function like

`[self.dogs removeAllObjects]`

is there any funcation like that for RLMResults or RLMArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a method exists for `RLMArray` with [`removeAllObjects`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMArray.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMArray(im)removeAllObjects). This means that you disassociate the object from all other linked objects within the array.

There is no such method for `RLMResults`, because instances of this class represent always the latest state of your query, which you can only mutate if you modify your underlying data. So if you query on a list, this would be implicitly possible by removing objects from the list. If you query on all objects (/ a table), then you would need either delete the objects from the Realm or modify them in such a way that they don't match your query anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Copy all objects from your RLMResults to a NSMutableArray and operate on that then.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete

```
RLMResults *tableDataArray;    
tableDataArray=[Dog allObjects];
[[RLMRealm defaultRealm] beginWriteTransaction];
//Deleting All Objects 
[[RLMRealm defaultRealm]deleteAllObjects];
//Remove particular object
[[RLMRealm defaultRealm]deleteObject:[tableDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];  // I use this in didSelectRowAtIndexPath
[[RLMRealm defaultRealm] commitWriteTransaction];
```

For adding

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
Dog *dog = [[Dog alloc] init];
dog.name=@"Puppy";
dog.city=@"New York";
[realm addObject:dog];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

For Updating

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
dog.name=@"Rosie";
dog.city=@"Washington";
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Comment: okies. thanks for your help. :) But I dun want to delete permanently from realm. I just want to remove from memory before I aded new results into that array.

Comment: You should follow above code if you wan to remove from array and add it array.